# Является ли функция функтором

Tags: c++, функции

Является ли функция функтором?

Функцию можно применять в качестве функтора в STL алгоритмах, но почему-то книги упорно доказывают, что функция это функция, а функтор - это именно объект

Comment: Что такое функтор?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В стандарте C++ нет такого термина, как функтор. Обычно в книгах под этим понятием подразумевают так называемый объект функции - термин, который действительно определен в стандарте C++.

Из стандарта C++ (20.9 Function objects)

> 1 A **function object type is an object type** (3.9) that can be the
>   type of the postﬁx-expression in a function call (5.2.2, 13.3.1.1).230
>   A function object is an object of a function object type. In the
>   places where one would expect to pass a pointer to a function to an
>   algorithmic template (Clause 25), the interface is speciﬁed to accept
>   a function object. This not only makes algorithmic templates work with
>   pointers to functions, **but also enables them to work with arbitrary
>   function objects**.

Поэтому под функторами авторы книг скорей всего имеют в виду объекты функций. Так как функции не относятся к типам объектов, то они не включаются в это понятие.

С другой стороны а сноске 230 написано относительно типа постфиксного выражения вызова функции

> 230) Such a type is a function pointer or a class type which has a
>   member operator() or a class type which has a conversion to a pointer
>   to function.

Тем не менее, алгоритмы могут принимать функции по ссылке, а не обязательно указатели на функции.

Сама приведенная цитата может трактоваться неоднозначно. Думаю, что ключом к ее правильной трактовке является следующая фраза из приведенной цитвты

> In the places where one would expect to pass a pointer to a function
>   to an algorithmic template (Clause 25), the interface is speciﬁed to
>   accept a function object.

Именно здесь, вероятно, авторы книг проводят водораздел между объектами, которые предоставляют оператор функцию, и простыми указателями на функции, называя первых функторами.

Comment: Может быть *функциональный объект*?

Comment: @Arhad Я думаю, что в этом случае ближе подошло бы английское словосочетание functional object. Однако в стандарте используется именно function object.

Answer (score 7):

Основное отличие функции от функтора заключается в том, что функция не имеет состояния, а функтор, являющийся объектом, обладать состоянием может.

Конечно, можно предложить к рассмотрению частный случай, когда внутри функции определена статическая переменная, или используется какая-то внешняя (глобальная) переменная. Но такие функции нельзя будет использовать в двух разных контекстах, т.к. состояние будет общее. Использование функтора (т.е. объекта, с перегруженным `operator()`) позволяет разделять состояние для разных вызовов.

Так же типы функторов могут использоваться в качестве параметров шаблона. Разные типы функторов позволят получать разные типы инстанцированных объектов, даже если сигнатуры `operator()` у них одинаковые. А если у Вас есть две разные функции с одинаковыми сигнатурами, например, `int g(double)`, `int f(double)`, то тип этих функций всё равно будет одинаковый `int(double)`.

Comment: **функция не имеет состояния** - а как же статические переменные внутри функции? да, это не совсем как у объектов, но все же.

Comment: у вас абстракция понятия функтора и реализация слились. То как реализован функтор это другое. Кто сказал, что все функторы обязаны иметь переменные состояния?

Comment: @KoVadim во втором абзаце об этом написано. Или Вы имели в виду что-то еще?

Comment: @rikimaru2013 я сказал, что он *может* обладать состоянием, а не *обязан*.

Comment: @alexolut я лишь веду к тому, что ваши доводы завязаны на недостатки реализации. Ни слова в стандарте про внутреннее состояние или обязательную разницу в сигнатурах

Comment: @rikimaru2013 так в Стандарте и понятия функтора нет, о чем Вам указали в другом ответе. Вас это не смущает?

Comment: @тогда получается и вопроса не существует где присутствует слово функтор - но вы сумели на него ответить) Меня это больше смущает)

Comment: @rikimaru2013 возможно сработал ген дедушки Нострадамуса, а может даже бабушки Ванги :) Но для полноты картины Вам хорошо было бы привести в вопросе цитаты из книг с указанием ISBN. Допускаю, что в таком случае ответы могли бы быть более предметны.

Answer (score 1):

Да запросто.
Просто это - **вызываемый объект**.
Функция - вызываема? несомненно.
Объект? А почему нет? Что такое указатель, как не объект определенного типа?

Короче, функция - это частный случай функтора, только и всего.